# Compiler-rt and gcc?

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm-clang

As far as I understand, compiler-rt provides a list of target-specific software emulation for its respective hardware counterpart. For example, if a system doesn't have a double to double multiplication, than its respective software rountine will be called.

My question is, how is this different from GCC standard library? How do use it for cross-compilation? Are compiler-rt software emulated functions more optimized than, lets say, using arm-gcc library functions for the same operation?

Am I understanding this issue correctly?